# Removing Handle keyword from DSpace url

Tags: handle, dspace

I am not using handler in DSpace 6.1 but still by default I can see handle keyword in URL.Tried tomcat rewrite conditions but getting 404 error because those pages don't exist.I am trying to change it to look like http://mywebiste/123456789/23 instead of http://mywebsite/handle/123456789/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from a trivial change to make. If you are using XMLUI, the place to look at and alter is sitemap.xmap

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/sitemap.xmap#L257

You will notice there that there are ~10 locations where /handle/ is referenced in the path.

If the underlying problem is that you don't want to register with CNRI for a handle, and that you don't want to be stuck with the generic 123456789 in the url, know that you can also change this prefix into a word, instead of a number.

So for example, you can change 123456789 into "internal", so you have item page urls like:

https://rdmc.nottingham.ac.uk/handle/internal/7006